# My ~/.ssh directory was deleted

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I created a Bitbucket/git the account. For some reason, I messed up the stuffs and failed to push up the repo.
In a hurry I deleted my ~/.ssh directory.

So how to repair it?

Comment: Restore from latest backup ?

Comment: I am not sure I have a backup and I am a bitbucket newbie.

Comment: Then you'll need to simply generate a new RSA key, see my answer, and the links as well. Regerating key isn't the end of the world, and with all of the collateral damage of Heartbleed, might not be the worst thing in the world right about now (though heartbleed didn't affect SSH specifically, it has allowed a lot of compromised keys/info to leak).

Comment: Once you do create a new private key, immediately back it up offline. I store mine on a thumb drive, dangling over a moat, guarded by sharks, with laser beams. Just kidding. I couldn't afford the sharks.

Comment: Take home message: it's time to implement a proper backup strategy - this time it was just your .ssh directory, next time it could be something that you can't afford to lose.

Comment: *There are only two types of people in the world: Them that have lost data, and them that will.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what was in your .ssh dir.

Typically, the .ssh directory contains 3 kinds of file:

```
1) id_rsa / id_dsa / id*.pub - These are your private and public keys; your identity;
the key(s) that authenticate you to the remote SSH (git) server. If you lost the private
key, and don't have a backup then you are out of luck and will have to create a brand
new private/public keypair, and repeat the process you originally went through to
authorize your ssh/git client. In short, run ssh-keygen to generate new keys (today I recommend
you use 2048 bit length), and then proceed to Bitbucket to register your new public key
with the server.

2) If you also used authorized_keys, you will need to recreate that file or
find a backup. Those are only _public_ keys from other hosts that you use to login to
"this" host using key based authentication. If this is just a client machine, you likely
wont have an authorized_keys file.

3) known_hosts - The public server keys of SSH servers that you have accepted
in past sessions. It will be auto-created next time you connect to a
remote SSH server and accept a key forever. It is maintained by your SSH
clients, so don't worry about that file. You will, however, receive warnings as if
you've never connected to servers before until the file is fully repopulated.
```

So the important one is (1),  your private key is not replaceable without a backup.

**Bitkeeper**:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

In case the link ever goes bad, in short you use ssh-keygen to generate an RSA key (Google ssh-keygen), then you need to go to Bitkeeper Account settings and add in the id_rsa.pub (public key) portion.

**Github** is similar:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Lastly, always make a backup of your private key file on a thumb drive that you store in a physically secure place.

Comment: I had the same problem, but now I cannot login remotely to any of the hosts. It says "connect to host ___ port 22: Operation timed out". It doesn't even ask me for my password as it did previously. What may be wrong?